# Regex - Difference between ^(abc|a)$ and ^abc|a$

Tags: python, regex

I have the input word `abcab` and the two following regular expressions:

`^abc|(abc(abc|a))$`
`^(abc|(abc(abc|a)))$`

Why does the first regex return the match `abc`, while the second one matches nothing (intended behavior)?

The only difference are the brackets between `^` and `$` and as far as I'm concerned this shouldn't change anything.

I tested it on regex101.com with Python regex.

Comment: (Can you explain why you expected something else?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was in my head and thought about ^$ being parenthesis themselves :$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the parenthesis causing the `|`s to split only within a group (and leave everything outside that group unmodified), the `^` and `$` only apply to whichever result of the split you're on.

That is to say, `^abc|(abc(abc|a))$` means either:

- `^abc` (opening anchor only, no closing anchor; so `abc` followed by *anything else* is a successful match)

or

- `(abc(abc|a))$` (closing anchor only, no opening anchor; so *anything* ending in either `abcabc` or `abca` is a successful match).